# How to improve performance of MySQL dump restore

Tags: mysql

Many of us who are working on their home or pet projects and who use databases for storing structured data may encounter performance issues when trying to dump/restore data. It can annoying just to sit and wait for another dump restore operation for dozens of minutes or even for hours.

I have quite typical machine specs - 4 core i5 7300, 8 Gb RAM, quite fast M2 drive and Windows 10/MySQL 5.7.

The problem was that trying to restore ~4.5Gb file it took more **than 4 hours**. That was ridiculous and I wondered if `mysqld` process isn't using even a half of system resources - CPU/Memory/Disk I/O

Generally speaking, this post relates to some kind of summary of related issues including credits to many other posts which I put below

Answer (score 24):

I performed a number of experiments with MySQL parameters for better dump restore operations

```
+--------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+
|           Parameter            | Default | Changed | Performance (minutes) | Perfomance gain (%) |
+--------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| All default                    | -       | -       | 259 min               | -                   |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size        | 8M      | 4G      | 32 min                | +709%               |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size        | 4G      | 6G      | 32 min                | ~0%                 |
| innodb_log_file_size           | 48M     | 1G      | 11 min                | +190%               |
| innodb_log_file_size           | 1G      | 2G      | 10 min                | +10%                |
| max_allowed_packet             | 4M      | 128M    | 10 min                | ~0%                 |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit | 1       | 0       | 9 min 25 sec          | +5%                 |
| innodb_thread_concurrency      | 9       | 0       | 9 min 27 sec          | ~0%                 |
| innodb_double_write            | -       | off     | 8 min 5 sec           | +18%                |
+--------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

**Summary (for best dump restore performance)**:

1. Set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to half of RAM
2. Set `innodb_log_file_size` to 1G
3. Set `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` to 0
4. Disabling `innodb_double_write` recommended only for fastest performance, it should be enabled on production. I also found, that changing another related parameter `innodb_flush_method` didn't change performance. But this can be an issue of Windows platform.
5. If you have complex structure with a lot of foreign keys for example, you can try Bulk Data Loading for InnoDB Tables tricks, link is listed at bottom of page
6. As you can see, I tried to increase CPU utilization by setting `innodb_thread_concurrency` to 0 (and also setting `innodb_read_io_threads` to maximum of 64) but results didn't change - it seems that `mysqld` process is already quite efficient for multi-core environment.
7. Restoring only data (without table structure) also didn't affect performance

I also changed a number of other parameters, but those above are most relevant ones for dump restore operation so far.

**It may seem obvious, but novice question can be - where I can find and set those settings**?

In Windows, `my.ini` file is located at `ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server <version>/my.ini`. You won't find some settings there (like `innodb_double_write`) - it's ok, just add to the end of the file.

The best way to change settings is to use MySQL Workbench (`Server > Options file > InnoDB`).

**I pay my credits to following posts (and a lot of similar ones), which I found very useful**:

https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/02/22/restore-mysql-logical-backup-maximum-speed/
https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/28/10-mysql-performance-tuning-settings-after-installation/
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86636/when-is-it-safe-to-disable-innodb-doublewrite-buffering
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html

Comment: If you would post TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; and SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after completing a DUMP / RESTORE we can find additional performance improvement suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you have MySQL 8.0.21 and above.  Note the following is **very** risky, so only do the following if you are doing a data load to a clean database **instance** not just schema.

- [disable redo logging](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-redo-log.html#innodb-disable-redo-logging) (which also disables double write buffering) *this is the important setting*
- disable foreign key checks
- set `innodb_file_per_table` to OFF [DBA question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16208/why-using-innodb-file-per-table) and [why I chose `OFF`](https://www.percona.com/blog/performance-problem-with-innodb-and-drop-table/) when I was doing my tests (emphasis mine)

  > So as result of this bug – if you’re running innodb_file_per_table you will have a microstalls when tables are dropped and **dropping a lot of tables in a batch** can cause serve performance problems. The stalls can take more than a second for very large buffer pool.

In addition do the following from @Anton's answer

- `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` to 0

From my actual tests to do a restore and anonymization post processing of data.  The disabling of the redo logging reduced the time from nearly 2 hours to under 30 minutes.

To set it as part of the restore and anonymization sequence, here are the key parts of the restore script

```bash
cat dump.sql | mysql **username/password** \
  --init-command='ALTER INSTANCE DISABLE INNODB REDO_LOG; SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;'

cat anonymize.sql | mysql **username/password** \
  --init-command='ALTER INSTANCE DISABLE INNODB REDO_LOG; SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;'
```